# SKPSMTPMessage notification when it has finished sending the email for MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I'm having an issue with SKPSMTPMessage and MBProgressHUD.

SKPSMTPMessage is working fine. Emails are being sent and no issues here.

SKPSMTPMessage is being called on the main thread. Before sending the email, MBProgressHUD starts an indeterminate progress mode. This works fine.
The problem is removing the MBProgressHUD.

After the email it sent a call to SKPSMTPMessage's delegate

```
(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message"
```

is made. In here I am doing some memory clean up and removing the HUD.

However, I can verify that even after the "messageSent" delegate is called and executed, additional elements in SKPSMTPMessage are called. I would assume that before of this my HUD does not get removed until "a few seconds later"

Does anyone know if there are additional delegates or callbacks I could check from SKPSMTPMessage to know when it has been completely finish?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate has only two methods:

```
@protocol SKPSMTPMessageDelegate
@required

-(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message;
-(void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

From [Source Code](https://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/browse/releases/14/SKPSMTPMessage.h)

So i don't think you can get additional info.

Comment: Yeah I know it has those 2 methods in the delegate, but I wanted to know if there's a way to find out when all of the network connections or elements have been cleared out since "messageSent" doesn't seem to be the last method

Comment: What makes you think, that it's doing something noteworthy?
You can look in the [Source Code](https://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/browse/trunk/SMTPSender/Classes/SKPSMTPMessage.m) yourself.

Comment: To be sure you can try to call `[message dealloc]`. That should end every activity.